# magento projects opens as php code on ubuntu

Tags: magento2

I'm deploying on ubuntu ec2 instance, but when I tried to open the store, it open index.php code instead of running it

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

this is a webserver issue (virtual host to the least), I found an article for you, please read [How to setup webserver to run php files instead of downloading them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)